# message.content is not printable/writeable in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to make a chat logger for a discord server I run that looks at a conversation takes the messages and store them in a txt file. I am unsure of any ways to log this as my current code can only log contents that mention the bot itself. I do have the intent set to true on the discord application portal, do I need to actually do anything in the code to allow it to get the contents of any message?

`

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    usermessage = "{} {} {}".format(dt_string, message)
    with open('data/discord/log.txt', 'a+') as y:
        y.write(usermessage + '\n')
    print(message.content)
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

`

I tried making the message var into a str using
`text = str(message.content)`
but it gave the message content when the bot was mentioned.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear for me; You would like a bot which would log private chats between to participants? If that's the case, I don't really think there is a solution for your problem, as the bot can only log, what it sees

Comment: I'm trying to make a bot that can log a discord server chat.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using
`client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())`
I should have set it to
`client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())`
It was a very silly mistake of mine, I apologize.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let me save you the problem with a fix that works for me, however I'm using discord.py with pycord which is a wrapper.

```py
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    channel = bot.get_channel('') 
    messages = await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()
    for message in messages:
        if not message.attachments:
            print(f"{message.guild.name}:", message.author, message.content)
        else:
            print(message.author, message.attachments)
```

It will print the message into your terminal, along with the author and the guild in which the message came from, hope this helps!